# How to embed JComponent in html element in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I have JTextPane with html content, I add set StyleSheet with my CSS rules to it.
I want to insert JComponent in my html element, so that CSS rules execute on it.
The html would be like this:

```
   <body>
        <div id = 'content'>
            <p class = 't'>t</p>
            <p class = 'k'>k</p>
            <div class = 'hascomp'>
                <span class = 'desc'>description</span>
                <br/>
                // here I want to insert my java component
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

and following is my java code to create element with hascomp class:

```
try {
        doc.insertBeforeEnd(content, "<div class = 'hascomp'><span class = 'desc'>"+description+"</span><br/>");
    } catch (BadLocationException | IOException  e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int offset = Pane.getDocument().getLength();
    Pane.setCaretPosition(offset);
    Pane.insertComponent(jcomponent);
    try {
        doc.insertBeforeEnd(content, "</div>");
    } catch (BadLocationException | IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

CSS for hascomp class:

```
.hascomp {font : 10px monaco; background-color:#E15AE3;margin : 2px;padding : 1px 10px;border-radius: 4px;border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: #D5D3CD;text-align: left;clear: both;float: left; }
```

but it didn't work correctly.

[here is picture of running code](http://i58.tinypic.com/v8kj5v.png)

So, how can I embed JComponent in html element in JTextPane?!

Comment: for JComponent, Icon to use JEditorPane

Comment: http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html for custom tag e.g. button

Comment: the component which I want to embed is jtextpane which contains jwebbrowser!

Answer (score 0):

I worked hard on this subject. The only solution I found is to insert the tags with insertHTML from HTMLEditorKit

You can do it like this :

```
protected void insertComponent(Component c, long id) {
  if (this.getSelectedText() != null && this.getSelectedText().length()>0) {
    try {
      htmlDoc.remove(this.getSelectionStart(), this.getSelectedText().length());
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Editeur.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
  int position = getSelectionStart();
  MutableAttributeSet inputAttributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();
  StyleConstants.setComponent(inputAttributes, c); //add component
  inputAttributes.addAttribute(COMPONENT_ID_ATTRIBUTE, id);//add id attribute
  insertComponent(position, id, c, inputAttributes);
}
private boolean insertComponent(int position, String id, Component c, AttributeSet inputAttributes) {
  try {
    String toInsert = "<span id='"+id+"'>&nbsp;</span>";
    int pushDepth, popDepth;
    pushDepth = isEOL(position-1) ? 1 : 0;//HACK:you have to check for end-of-lines before current position
    popDepth = pushDepth;
    editorKit.insertHTML(htmlDoc, position, toInsert, popDepth, pushDepth, Tag.SPAN);
    htmlDoc.setCharacterAttributes(position, 1, inputAttributes, false);
    //HACK you need to add/remove a dummy element to refresh the document structure. I didn't succeed with normal commands...
    htmlDoc.insertString(position+1, " ", null);
    htmlDoc.remove(position+1, 1);
    return true;
  } catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Editeur.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  return false;
}
```